# How to make web page Bokeh plot appear with same resolution as show(fig)?

Tags: python, html, flask, bokeh

I was able to make a web based bokeh plot using flask and html, but the plot on the web page appears to have lower resolution (Screenshot 1) and reduced clarity compared to the one plotted via "show(fig) in Bokeh" (Screenshot 2). I have tried to change the html tags from bokeh 1.4.0 to 2.0.0 and added class as "bokeh" for html div but, this wont change the resolution on web. How do i make the web page plot same resolution as the ones plotted via show(fig)? Appreciate any leads

***update: i have edited the code to plot only one group and updated the bokeh from 1.2.0 to 2.0.2 on conda  and this is not letting me see graph via show(plot) in my browser. So, the screenshots you may see below are an example from previous runs ***

I use google chrome: 83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)

python 3.7

bokeh 2.0.2

app.py

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from bokeh.embed import components
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from random import randint
from bokeh.io import show

f_12 = pd.Series(['f1', 'f2'])
f_12 = f_12.repeat(50)

sample_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': [randint(100, 1000) for p in range(0, 100)]
                          ,'y': np.random.random(100)
                          ,'filter_12': f_12
                          , 'group': [randint(1, 2) for p in range(0, 100)]
                         })

f12_list = sample_df['filter_12'].unique().tolist()
group_list = sample_df['group'].unique().tolist()

def compute( f_12, group_f):
        small_df = sample_df.loc[(sample_df['filter_12'] == f_12) & (sample_df['group'] == group_f) ]   
        x = small_df['x'].values
        y = small_df['y'].values
        fig=figure(x_axis_label="x",y_axis_label="y")

        popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda fx,a,b: a+b*np.log(fx),  x,  y)
        #popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,  x,  y)
        y_cal = popt[1]*np.log(x) + popt[0]       
        fig.line(x, y_cal, color='green', legend_label="Green_Line_fit")
        fig.circle(x, y, color='green', legend_label='A')

        return fig

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
# Index page
@app.route('/')
def main():
   return redirect('/index')

@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', f12_list=f12_list, group_list=group_list)


@app.route('/plot', methods=['POST'])
def results():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f_12 = request.form.get('f_12')
        if f_12 == None:
            f_12 = "f1"
        group_f = request.form.get('selected_group')
        if group_f == None:
            group_f = 1        
        plot = compute(f_12, int(group_f))
        show(plot)
                # Embed plot into HTML via Flask Render
        script, div = components(plot)
        return render_template("index.html", script=script, div=div, f12_list=f12_list, group_list=group_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.0.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.0.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<H1>Chart</H1>

<form action="/plot" method="POST">
<select name="f_12" id="f_12">
    {% for f12 in f12_list %}
        {% if f12 == f_12 %}
            <option selected value="{{ f12 }}">{{ f12 }}</option> 
        {% else %} 
            <option value="{{ f12 }}">{{ f12 }}</option> 
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<select name="selected_group" id="selected_group">
    {% for group in group_list %}
        {% if group == selected_group %}
            <option selected value="{{ group }}">{{ group }}</option> 
        {% else %} 
            <option value="{{ group }}">{{ group }}</option> 
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<div class="bokeh">
{{ div|safe }}
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.0.2.min.js"></script>

{{ script|safe }}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot 1 (webpage - google chrome)

[image]

Screenshot 2 (show(fig) plot on google chrome, bokeh version 1.2.0)

[image]

Comment: There really should not be any difference on the Bokeh end, and I certainly can't think of anything that would explain this apart from the browser being different. If you can provide a complete minimal reproducer that can reliably demonstrate a difference on the same browser, you should submit a GitHub issue (https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) with full details.

Comment: @bigreddot thanks, added my issue on github.

Comment: @user12229564 Any updates on this? I'm also trying to do something similar.